# Font size expressed in VW on IE9 are bigger

Tags: css, internet-explorer-9, font-size, viewport-units

Basically I am designing a jquery plugin to create circular presentation using **vw** to get rid of font size.
Everything works fine except for IE9, which renders the size of the font bigger than the other browser.
You can take a look at the example here:

http://www.rubenrizzi.com/circularslideshow/example-cell-encrypted/

Looks how bigger looks on IE9 than in the other browser.

Is there a way to handle this behavior with a polyfill, or a css trick to make IE9 respect the **vw** size?

Comment: Everyone hates IE9 I suppose...